# Magento 2: Custom product attribute in FinalPrice afterGetValue

Tags: magento2, plugin, eav-attributes

I have created a plugin to modify the final price with afterGetValue.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice" shared="false">
    <plugin name="my_module_plugin_product_price" type="My\Module\Plugin\Product" disabled="false" sortOrder="999" />
</type>
```

Plugin:

```
namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetValue(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $subject, $result) : float
    {
        $product = $subject->getProduct();
        // Does not work unless loaded
        $product->load($product->getId()); 
        return $product->getFinalPrice() * $product->getUnits();
    }
}
```

The price should be modified based upon a product's custom eav attribute ("units"). But unless the product get's fully loaded the attribute value is not available.

How can I tell magento to always load a custom attribute?

**EDIT:** I found out that placing a `catalog_attributes.xml` into the etc folder of my module is supposed to achieve exactly what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_product">
        <attribute name="units" />
    </group>
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="units" />
    </group>
</config>
```

Unfortunately it does not work at all (magento 2.2.7). Am I missing something?